# Tikz: How do you label a circled node to the left without collisions?

Tags: nodes, labels

I'm trying to label a circled node in Tikz with some text to the left. The problem is it is colliding with the circle.

For example I have something like:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw,circle] at (0,0) {A};
\node[left] at (0,0) {010101};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

This causes the binary to overlap the node A. What is the best way to fix this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One way to fix this is to load the `positioning` library

[image]

Note that in the code below I have named your first node as `nameofnode` and then positioned the text in relation to it by using `left=of nameofnode`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw,circle](nameofnode) at (0,0) {A};
\node[left=of nameofnode] {010101};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm trying to work out how to get the binary label a bit closer now.

Comment: @Andrew Try `left=<distance> of nameofnode` and vary `<distance>`.

Answer (score 16):

An even easier version is using the `label` option for nodes:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[draw,circle,label=left:010101] (CircleNode) at (0,0)  {A};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

It looks just like Peter Grill's solution.

Answer (score 8):

Instead of placing the text node at via coordinates, you could name the circle node and place it to the `left` of the named circled node:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[draw,circle] (CircleNode) at (0,0)  {A};
  \node[left] at (CircleNode.west) {010101};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```